# PHP extract string after @

Tags: php, mysql, preg-match-all

I need a PHP function to extract a string after @ 
For example on Facebook, if you write @username, username will be automatically replace with profile URL. I want to do something like that, to detect @username, to see if username exists in database and if exists, then script will return his profile URL. I know to check if username exists into database and to generate profile URL, but I don't know how to detect @username from the string (also can be @username1, @username2, etc. on the same string). I will really appreciate if you can give me an example or provide me a function to do that. Thank you!

Comment: Look up [`preg_replace_callbac()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)

Comment: What are valid characters for usernames?

Comment: I use this function to validate usernames: preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z]{4,16})?([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]{4,16})$/i",$login)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but regex replace with `(@[A-Za-z0-9]{1,})`

find any character A-z0-9 (what is usually accepted as username)

```
$text = preg_replace_callback(
        '@([A-Za-z0-9]{1,})',
        function ($matches) {
            return '<a href="profileURL">'.$matches[1].'</a>';
        },
        $text
    );
```

**UPDATE**

Based on comment, you can generate an array with

`preg_match_all('@([A-Za-z0-9]{1,})', $text, $matches);`

This will return a multidimensional array with `$matches[0]` being the original text and `$matches[1]` with an array of the found names (minus @)

Comment: Why not `preg_replace('/(@[A-Za-z0-9]{1,})/', '<a href="profileURL">$1</a>', $text);`?

Comment: Thank you, but I need to extract all those usernames in array, then I will use this array to validate and check one by one, to see if username exists into database or not. If exists, I will generate an URL, if not I will leave it as it is. The problem is that I don't know how to extract all those usernames, after all @ from string.

Comment: @Amal You could do that but by providing a callback `profileURL` can be replaced to the actual url. @Alexander alternative if you just need an array see my update.

Answer (score 1):

If your are sure that "@" will only occur once in string then you can use use the php function to skip the first character and take the rest of it. Or else use str_replace() to replace "@" from the string. But if there is possibility of getting ore than "@" symbols in the string, then probably you can use explode() for "@" and get all the strings only. But yes you have to check for validations in the array that you will received.